strong limit of operators and and weak limit for function
Consider the family of operators in Hilbert space $A(t)$, $t \in [0, \infty)$, $ \| A(t) \| \leq M$, $\forall t \in [0, \infty) $. Let there be convergence to zero in the strong operator topology $A(t) \to 0$, $t \to \infty$ in SOT. Let there be a function $F(t)$, it is known that $\left\{ F(t), t \in [0, \infty) \right\}$ belongs a weakly compact set. more precisely, it is known that the set $F(t)$ is bounded, whence weak compactness follows. Can we assert the existence of a limit $A(t)F(t), t \to \infty$ in any topology, weak topology for example?
And connected question. Now, let $F(t)$ if familiar of operator and $\left\{ F(t), t \in [0, \infty) \right\}$ be compact set in SOT. Can we assert the existence of a operators limit $A(t)F(t), t \to \infty$ in any topology?

No. Let $v$ be the unilateral shift on $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Define,
$$A(t) = (v^\ast)^{\lfloor t \rfloor}$$
$$F(t) = \begin{cases}
v^{\lfloor t \rfloor}, \; \lfloor t \rfloor \text{ is even}\\
v^{\lfloor t \rfloor + 1}, \; \lfloor t \rfloor \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
Then for all $t$, $\|A(t)\|, \|F(t)\| = 1$. $A(t) \to 0$ in SOT. But,
$$A(t)F(t) = \begin{cases}
1, \; \lfloor t \rfloor \text{ is even}\\
v, \; \lfloor t \rfloor \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
So $A(t)F(t)$ does not converge to anything in any (Hausdorff) topology, in particular it does not converge in WOT.
Additional remark: While $A(t)F(t)$ needs not converge, we do have $F(t)A(t) \to 0$ in SOT. Also, if we have, in addition, that $A(t)^\ast \to 0$ in SOT, then we would have $A(t)F(t) \to 0$ in WOT, but not necessarily in SOT.

For your related question: if $\{F(t): t \in [0, \infty)\}$ is precompact in SOT (i.e., its SOT closure is SOT compact), then $A(t)F(t) \to 0$ in SOT. Indeed, for any subnet $t_\lambda$ (of $t \to \infty$), by SOT precompactness, there exists a further subnet $t_{\lambda_\eta}$ s.t. $F(t_{\lambda_\eta}) \to F$ in SOT for some operator $F$. But multiplication is SOT continuous when the first argument is uniformly bounded, so $A(t_{\lambda_\eta})F(t_{\lambda_\eta}) \to 0 \cdot F = 0$ in SOT. But this means for any subnet $t_\lambda$, there is a further subnet $t_{\lambda_\eta}$ under which $A(t_{\lambda_\eta})F(t_{\lambda_\eta}) \to 0$ in SOT, so $A(t)F(t) \to 0$ in SOT.
